# how can i store the user Id after login using ionic2 framework

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, authentication, ionic2

i'm new to ionic 2 and i have a problem in storing my user data that i have stored in a class in my injectable service for login please help me:

**auth-service.ts**

```
   export class User {
   nom: string;
   email: string;

     constructor(nom: string, email: string) {
    this.nom = nom;
    this.email = email;
 }
}
    @Injectable()
     export class AuthService {
     currentUser: User;
     members: Array<any>;
     nomUser:string;
     emailUser:string;

        constructor(public http: Http) {
               console.log('Hello Authentification');
             }

      public login(credentials) {
      if (credentials.email === null || credentials.password === null) {
       return Observable.throw("Please insert credentials");
       } else {
        return Observable.create(observer => {
        var url = 'http://localhost/PFEBACKEND/login-client.php?
       email='+credentials.email+'&passe='+credentials.password ;

         this.http.get(url).map(res => res.json()).subscribe(
          data=>{                                                                       
                let access = (data.error=== 0 )

                 this.currentUser = new User( data.nom,data.email);

                 console.log(this.currentUser);
                   observer.next(access);  
                   observer.complete(); 
                    },
                    err => {
                    console.log(err);
                    },
                      () => console.log('authentifié') );

                });
   }

          public getUserInfo()  {
            return  this.currentUser ;
          }
```

**home.ts**

```
import { AuthService } from '../../providers/auth-service';
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Component,Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams,LoadingController  } from 'ionic-angular';

    export class HomePage {
          nom:string= '';
          email:string= '';

    constructor(public http: Http,public navCtrl: NavController, private 
    auth:AuthService,public data:Datamembers, public navParams:NavParams, 
     public loadingCtrl:LoadingController)
   {      
     let info = this.auth.getUserInfo();
     this.email = info.email;
     this.nom = info.nom; 
   }
  }
```

**Error:**

> nav-controller-base.js:88 Failed to navigate:  Cannot read property 
>   'email' of undefined    (anonymous) @ nav-controller-base.js:88
>   core.es5.js:1085 
>       ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 
>       'email' of undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have got most part right except this - you cannot return data directly from an observable to a calling class from a method. You need to pass that observable. Parse it in the calling class. Let me correct this for you.

```
return Observable.create(observer => {
  var url = 'http://localhost/PFEBACKEND/login-client.php?email='+credentials.email+'&passe='+credentials.password ;

 this.http.get(url).map(res => res.json()).subscribe(
   data=>{                                                                       
       let access = (data.error=== 0 )

       this.currentUser = new User( data.nom,data.email);

       console.log(this.currentUser);
       observer.next(this.currentUser);  
       observer.complete(); 
   },
   err => {
      console.log(err);
      observer.error(err);
   },
   () => console.log('authentifié') 
);
```

And in **home.ts**:

```
this.auth.getUserInfo().subsribe((data) => {
    this.email = data.email;
    this.nom = data.nom;
},(err) => {
  console.log("Error :",err);
});
```

**NOTE:** Here I am assuming that `this.currentUser, access` are important to you. If they are not and finally if you need everything in `home.ts`, you just need to remove both of these statements and do `observer.next(data);` there.

Comment: thank you soooo much!!! @sagar it worked but i have struggle on how to save a user and their infos after login ?? i worked with a class named User in my authentication service but once i refresh the page all the infos are gone

Comment: Where do you want to store it? Regardless, the question is answered. Glad it helped. :)

Comment: i have a database but i don't know what's best for login informations !!maybe local storage !! what u think ?

Comment: If you want to store it in the app side then YES. Easiest way is `localStorage.setItem('email',this.email);` and you can retrieve it from anywhere in the app like `localStorage.getItem('email')`. Also, since it has solved your problem please accept it an close this question. :)

Comment: this is my first post sorry :p i'm so thankfull for your help  !!

Comment: No problem. Everyone here's to help. :) It is just easy if the questions are well explained. Also, as @sampath said : from next time update your code in question itself. You can edit your own question to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to `resolve` an `email` inside the `promise` as shown below.

```
 this.auth.getUserInfo().then((i) => {
     this.email = i.email;
     this.nom = i.nom; 
  }
```

Comment: my function **getUserInfo** returns a User object wich contains  "email" and "nom"  

 public getUserInfo() : User {
    return this.currentUser;
  }     **i have a class** named User in my service :                                      
     export class User {
      nom: string;
      email: string;
 
  constructor(nom: string, email: string) {
    this.nom = nom;
    this.email = email;
  }
} when i tried your solution i get an error in **.then(** cause getUserInfo() contains only "nom" and "email" !! please help me !!

Comment: i did this in home.ts **this.email= this.auth.getUserInfo().email;**
   **this.nom=this.auth.getUserInfo().nom;** and when i tried to print them in home.html **{{email}}** i get the same error

Comment: Can you put `getUserInfo()` detail on your original question? Don't put that on comment area.Cannot read it.

Comment: Here `return Observable.create(observer => {` don't you have a method?

Comment: it's a login function ..or u mean a method after this lign?